After "Squash and Merge" on GitHub, is there a way to find that "Squash Commit"? (to cherry-pick)
On GitHub, let's say I committed 12 times (following the "commit often" practice) and now the PR is ready, and I finally got it all reviewed and approved, and clicked on "Squash and Merge" on GitHub.
However, due to some side effect, it was reverted. So after a day later, I need to use the current master or main, and apply those 12 changes.
I can cherry-pick those 12 commits, but it'd be easier if I can just cherry-pick that one commit (that was squashed).
Is there a way to find that commit, and use cherry-pick to get all those changes in one command line?

git fetch followed by git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all should give you a good overview how the branches are connected.

Starting from the GitHub PR, you should be able to locate the Git commit hash which you could cherry-pick. Inspecting the history should work, too. Apart from that, you can git cherry-pick abc123..def456 to pick a range of multiple commits. Lastly, if you still have the branch locally, just rebase it on main/master. If you don't have it locally any more, search git reflog for entries.

@UlrichEckhardt so that may work, if I can specify a range... abc123..def456 should be, for examples, all those 12 commits, all mine, and not including anything else... in the PR

Maybe, could be that we're misunderstanding each other, too. abc123 is supposed to be the first commit's hash, def456 that of the last you want to cherry-pick. Note that in addition to a commit hash, git supports other identifiers, like e.g. a branch name, tag name or a relative notation (e.g. HEAD~4). It's definitely worth getting familiar with these things. You don't need them very often, but then, they save you a lot of time.
